# Couldnt get session log while executing the wf through Autosys

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, autosys

while running an Wf through Autosys i am not able to open the session log in monitor were as if i run the same wf in workflow manger i am able to open the session log

can some1 pls help with this issue.

thanks

Comment: This seems to be access problem. Can you use the same user that is used in autosys to kick off infa workflows to check session log? if you use userx to kick off the workflow and you are usimg usery to check session log, you may be denied access to the logs.

Comment: Hi ,
In that wf we are having two sessions in which for 1 session i can open the session log for the other one i couldnt open
the session is getting failed but in wf log it is showing session as success.?

Comment: This means the session was not able to create the session log file. It may have failed. Worflow may still be successful - actually if `Fail parent if this task fails` checkbox is not set on session, the Workflow will succeed even when session fails.

Comment: is this issue resolved?